# Error while instantiating node js chaincode

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am working on a hyper ledger fabric project, I am able to set up the network and install and instantiate the go chain code successfully, but when I want to instantiate the node js chain code, I am getting an error saying

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode simplyfi:1.0 for transaction
```

Please help me out in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: can you post the complete command that you are using , not just the error logs

Comment: @Harshit , this is the command for instantiating , docker exec cli.org1 bash -c "peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.simplyfi.com:7050 --lang node -C simplyficommon -n simplyfi -v 1.0 -c '{\"Args\":[]}'"

Comment: is tls enabled ? and can you check the peer logs? try export ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
before running this command

Comment: @Harshit tls is not enabled. Can you please provide me the command to do check the peer logs.

Comment: docker logs <peer container id>